# Stream filter method with underscore

Tags: java, filter, java-8, java-stream

i was answering problems on codefights and i found this problem

inputArray without elements `k - 1, 2k - 1, 3k - 1` etc.

Example

> For inputArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] and k = 3,
>
> the output should be
>   extractEachKth(inputArray, k) = [1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10].

one of the answers was the following code which i couldn't understand.

```
int i;

int[] extractEachKth(int[] inputArray, int k)

{

   return Arrays.stream(inputArray).filter(__ -> ++i % k > 0).toArray();

}
```

Comment: `__` is variable name and valid as per java rule.This is `stream` API released with `Java 8`. You can find basic of stream api here -> http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams-2177646.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filter method of the stream excludes elements that the expression after the arrow evaluates to false.

In other words it keeps the values when the expression evaluates to true.

As pointed by @Snehal Patel in the comment, the `__` is variable containing the current value submitted to the filter. It is a common practice to use _ or __ as a name of an unused parameter (specially in Swift language for example).